# relation jv_commit already exists

Tags: spring-boot, javers

I am using JaVers version 5.8.8, Spring boot 2.1.5, PostgreSQL 42.2.8. Its running fine when application runs first time however error comes application starts second time and so on. It is mentioned in official documentation of JaVers that this issue was fixed in version 5.6.2 but i am using latest version 5.8.8 still this error persists. Below is the error stacktrace: -

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2020-01-21 18:30:04.506[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m59224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditController' defined in file [D:\billing-system-principal-service\target\classes\com\posti\billing\controller\AuditController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$165.0000000015AA1FF0.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.posti.billing.BillingServiceApplication.main(BillingServiceApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$165.0000000015AA1FF0.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk BIGINT NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_date_instant VARCHAR(30),
commit_id NUMERIC(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
) 
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.ddl(SchemaManagerImpl.java:91) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.create(SchemaManagerImpl.java:52) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureTable(JaversSchemaManager.java:229) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.schema.JaversSchemaManager.ensureSchema(JaversSchemaManager.java:47) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.ensureSchema(JaversSqlRepository.java:186) ~[javers-persistence-sql-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:186) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.ensureSchema(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:183) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.afterPropertiesSet(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:177) ~[javers-spring-jpa-5.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "jv_commit" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:311) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:274) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:269) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.ddl(SchemaManagerImpl.java:88) ~[polyjdbc-0.7.6.jar:na]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please help !! Its required urgently.

Comment: @Bartek Walacik : Do you have solution for this ?

Comment: If you think you found a bug you are supposed to report it to our Issues https://github.com/javers/javers/issues, please follow the Guidelines for Bug Reporting https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#guidelines-for-bug-reporting

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont know if its still a bug in JaVers, so asked at this place. Ideally if tables & sequences are created then it should avoid to create. Am i correct or does it work differently ? Anyways i have reported issue at the given link, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like bug in JaversSchemaManager:248:

```
if (schemaName != null) {
            return resultSet.next();
/*248*/            } else {
            String tableSchemaName;
            do {
                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    return false;
                }

                tableSchemaName = resultSet.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
            } while(tableSchemaName != null
                    && !tableSchemaName.equalsIgnoreCase("public")
                    && !tableSchemaName.equals("")
                    && (!(this.dialect instanceof MsSqlDialect) || !tableSchemaName.equalsIgnoreCase("dbo"))
                    && (!(this.dialect instanceof OracleDialect) || !tableSchemaName.equalsIgnoreCase("system"))
            );
```

while loop always exit with false if schema is not defined.
Use **.withSchema("SCHEME")** it helps for me.